# How to create multiple tables in a .db file with pandas / sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a function that loops through and returns me 3 separate `dataframe` objects.

How do I put these 3 `dataframe` objects into 1 `.db` file with 3 separate `tables`?

The below code is what I am currently using. It loops through each of the items I have, do the needful and return me a `Dataframe` object that I can put to sql after that.

```
for each_item in items:
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///" + my_variable_database_name + ".db", echo=False)
    connection = engine.connect()
    pandas.DataFrame.to_sql(my_function(each_item), each_item, con=engine, if_exists="replace")
    connection.close()
    print(each_item + " has been completed successfully.")
print("All completed.")
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: What's the problem here? Aren't you looping through items returning the my_function's dataframe with `to_sql` export to database?

Comment: Yes, but this creates 3 separate `.db` files, each with 1 table inside. I want to create 1 `.db` file, with 3 tables inside.

Comment: How do three dbs output here? What are the names of the databases? Obviously can't share the same. How does *my_variable_database_name* change within loop? Does this posted code match actual?

Answer (score 1):

I realize what I am doing wrong. Basically I just had to restructure my code. What I had done previously was to put `engine` in the loop, and set the name to be `each_item` instead of my specific database.

```
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///mydatabase.db", echo=False)

for each_item in items:
    connection = engine.connect()
    pandas.DataFrame.to_sql(my_function(each_item), name=each_item, con=engine, if_exists="replace")
    connection.close()
    print(each_item + " has been completed successfully.")
print("All completed.")
```

Comment: Also, move connection open and close outside loop as they do not need iteration.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait. That makes sense